# How to prevent image flash when transitioning with blur?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-filters

How to prevent flash on end of transition on filter: blur effect?
(I'm using chrome)
Snippet below to show problem.

```js
$(window).on('load',function( event ){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.sec').addClass('active')
  },1000)
})
```

```css
.sec {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/700/500);
  background-size: cover;
  
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
   -moz-filter: blur(20px);
   -o-filter: blur(20px);
   -ms-filter: blur(20px);
   filter: blur(20px);
}
.sec.active {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
 -moz-filter: blur(0px);
 -o-filter: blur(0px);
 -ms-filter: blur(0px);
 filter: blur(0px);
 transition: all 3s ease, transform 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec">
  
</div>
```

Comment: How is the solution any different from the given example?

Comment: @VXp test in Chrome, chrome has some issue with filters

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am and I did but I don't see any difference. :)

Comment: @VXp you don't see the flash at the end? or you see the flash on both of them? or you see no flash at all?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No flash at all. I won't say your solution doesn't solve the problem, apparently it does, but I don't see any visual difference between the two, maybe it's just me or maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to avoid the `blur` to go to 0, you may consider a value close like `0.5px`

```js
$(window).on('load', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sec').addClass('active')
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
.sec {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/700/500);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(20px);
}

.sec.active {
  filter: blur(0.5px);
  transition: all 3s ease, transform 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec">

</div>
```