# My image is flickering on hover

Tags: css, hover, mouse, blur, flicker

So I have a few images with a blur filter and when ever I hover over them it flickers it flashes out when I put my mouse over and again when I take it off. I have had this problem appear seemingly randomly as it happens on computers I am on but than other times it is randomly fine.

I have already tried `backface-visibility: visible|hidden|initial|inherit;`
 I have already tried   `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);`
 I have already tried    `-webkit-background-size: cover;`
  `-moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;`

none of which have had any effect. here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/leothetinyninja/wjnzof9x/ Please tell me if you know what the problem is.

Comment: on Chrome, right ?

Comment: Here it does not flicker. `figure:hover > #tes {
 /*filter: blur(6px);*/
 
 }` adds a blur though. I am using Chrome. It is very smooth.

Comment: `backface-visibility: visible|hidden|initial|inherit;` isn't valid. You can only use one of those - not all four at once. As for flicker, I couldn't get that to occur but if it is a bit random, then fair enough - browsers can be a bit strange sometimes.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249520/how-to-prevent-image-flash-when-transitioning-with-blur/50249624#50249624

Comment: another one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50269779/chrome-still-does-flicker-on-transition?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I decided to make my own question as others asking about the same problem got different answers that worked for them but not me 

as for using backface-visibility: (to many things) I misunderstood a different solution and put that in. its nothing though.

Comment: I have just got onto a different computer and no flicker. I have used many different computers now and it has happened on a few of them I think there is still a problem but I dont see how to fix it if it is only happening occasionnally

Answer (score 0):

Fix: I added a `filter: blur(0.5px);` to the default so it's always at least that way and it seems to have fixed it. Thank you everyone for answering though

Answer (score -3):

Try adding a 1 second transition for your hover. This will either fix it, or give you a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: This is probably more suitable as a comment than an answer. Edit: But I've just noticed you probably don't have enough reputation to leave one. This is something I dislike about StackOverflow but with a few high-quality answers you'll probably get enough reputation soon.